# How to record video with Raspicam on Raspberry Pi model B+?

Tags: raspbian, video, raspivid

When I run command:

```
raspivid -t 15000 -o > test_vid.h264
```

Raspicam's red light stays on, but I only get file `test_vid.h264` which size is 0 bytes.

Ras Pi still works fine.

I have googled that `raspivid` doesn't work properly on Raspberry Pi B+.

Should I get `raspivid` to work or are there any other programs for Rasbian jessie that I might use to test if my raspicam can record video?

Comment: Your mistake here is combining `-o` with redirection (`>`).

Comment: Look at my comment to Linus answer.

Comment: It would be an easy thing to get confused about if you are not familiar with orthodox [CLI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface) practices (e.g., the use of switches such as `-o`) and how POSIX shells such as bash redirect output.  Linus does a decent job of explaining that in this case.  WRT switches, aka. options, most CLI's have a "man page" explaining them that can be accessed with, e.g., `man whatever`.  The raspicam apps don't have these, but they do have "help" messages that can be invoked with `-h`.  Note that `>` is a shell feature, not the app's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-o` option for raspivid is used to set the output path where you want to record a video but you never set it to anything and instead you try to redirect the `stdout` stream to a file.

If you want really want to use `stdout` and pipe it into a file you can use the `-o` option with a dash. From the [documentation](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/raspbian/applications/camera.md):

> ```
>     --output,   -o      Output filename <filename>.
> ```
>
> Specify the output filename. If not specified, no file is saved. If
>   the filename is '-', then all output is sent to stdout.

```
raspivid -t 15000 -o - > test_vid.h264
```

That should work to record a simple video. However the simplest and most recommended way is to use the command below.

```
raspivid -t 15000 -o test_vid.h264
```

Comment: Thank you all. Command and attributes I used to record video with raspivid was from the book  "The Internet of Things Do-It-Yourself at Home Projects for Arduino, Raspberry Pi, and BeagleBone Black". You pointed out that there is a mistake in book.